# In AES-CCM is the TAG size a user parameter?

Tags: cryptography, aes

I am developping an AES library which supports [Counter with CBC-MAC mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CCM_mode) and I have a question about the TAG (MAC) size.

Is the TAG size an input that must be provided by user or it can be computed from other parameters like header size, IV (counter or nonce) size and returned to user?

In my library I declare a function as following:

```
AES-CCM(Encrypt, header, header size, Nounce, NonceSize, PlainText, 
          PlainTextSize, &TAGSize, &CipherText);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tag size is not really a function of the input, so it should be set by the user. Note that this is not the case for the nonce, which makes CCM a bit of a pain to program in, in my opinion.

I've checked with the Bouncy Castle libraries, and they use user input to determine the MAC size (though they will simply divide by 8 to get bytes). If the size is not given then they will use half of the block size of the algorithm (which will default to 8 bytes for AES, of course), which is the reasonable default.

Comment: OK, checked with Bouncy instead. http://srcrr.com/java/bouncycastle/bouncycastle/1.46/reference/org/bouncycastle/crypto/params/CCMParameters.html http://srcrr.com/java/bouncycastle/bouncycastle/1.46/reference/org/bouncycastle/crypto/params/AEADParameters.html http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk14/1.46/org/bouncycastle/crypto/modes/CCMBlockCipher.java

Comment: Even if it is too late, let me thank you owlstead for the confirmation